# Mac App Store keeps prompting me to upgrade iTunes

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore

This is a screenshot of the Mac App Store.

I have been updating iTunes for days. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to restart?

Comment: @Harcker Yes I did

Comment: Have you tried to kill all App Store  related processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Are you certain that you in fact have iTunes 12.5.1 installed?**

Have you manually checked the version?

Seriously, this may be a gift from heaven, if it is your phone. (Tagged as iOS and screenshot is MacOS so I will address both)

The problem is happening on mobile devices and Macs.

**The MacOS** fix is to manually download [iTunes 12.5.1 package](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1814?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) and install it that way.

If the link above to Apple's iTunes Download page does not load for you, here is the direct link to [Apple's main iTunes page](https://www.apple.com/itunes/).

**For iOS**, there seems to be a big problem with people reporting bricked phones.

Go to systems-->notification find the app you do not want to see notifications from and choose "None" as the alert style. Or you can completely kick any app from the notification center.

You can disable most unwanted pop-ups by setting Software Update/ App Store to not automatically check for updates.

Comment: No, it wasn't installed. I started iTunes and it prompt me to upgrade too ...

Comment: So if it is indeed iTunes for MacOS, use the download link to install manually. If it is for the phone, read the post and think it through, with some research.

Comment: Glad that it worked out, hopefully this will help others.

Comment: You might wanna attach this link to your answer too https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/031-77682-20160908-A3B6AB42-7541-11E6-901F-53F133D2D062/iTunes12.5.1.dmg ... The link you provided does not work for me though

Comment: Will do. The download package link? If so that is odd, as it does for me. I will post a generic link to Apple as well. Cheers